# How to create a group in mediawiki and assigned it to users with different type of permission

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have install **mediawiki**. How can I achieve following thing in **mediawiki**

1. how I can create a **group or assigned** it to user.
2. different group have **different permission** i.e read,edit,delete
3. after edit only approved revision display to user
4. any time admin can **unapproved revision**

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? What have you tired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a group: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights

Just refer to a group in php code.

From the above page: Here we are creating a group called "editor" that has permission to edit.  We remove those rights from everyone else:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createpage'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['createpage'] = false;  
$wgGroupPermissions['editor']['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['editor' ]['createpage'] = true;
```

Assigning users to a group: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Assigning_permissions

Use the [[Special:UserRights]] page.

Display only approved revisions: Use the [FlaggedRevs extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlaggedRevs)